# Array Visualizer Expression Evaluation error: Unsupported debug session type

Tags: ilnumerics

While working with Visual Studio Community and a trial version of ILNumerics Array visualizer, I cannot get the visualizer to evaluate any expression.

I tried on multiple projects, including fresh new ones from basic templates. Every time, I get an "Unsupported debug session type!":

[image]

Is there a specific debug setting required to make it work? I could not find any information anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change debugger type in the startup project. It used to be on "Mixed", but I had to change it to either "Native Only" for native C++ parts of my solution or "Managed Only" for managed parts of my solution.
I still don't understand why it would not work on fresh templates, but my guess is that it was still set to an automated value with which the Array Visualizer didn't know what to do.